# Automatically Resize Layers to Fit Canvas - Photoshop

Tags: canvas, size, photoshop

I am not sure it is a right place to ask a photoshop question or not. Any one if answers will be good for me. I have finished designing a PSD with canvas size width 800px. Now I want to increase canvas size width to 960pxs. It is fine I have done it using canvas size option in right below image size, but the problem is the layers I have already made are of same size which I have already drawn. Now due to increased canvas size, I need to re-align them to fit with 960pxs width canvas. Is there any option out there which can work for me. I want all layers should be automatically adjusted to canvas size when I give them extra space to right of canvas from 800px to 960pxs.

Answer (score 2):

Let's answer your question in code (normally ask Photoshop questions in [Graphic Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

in JavaScript you can resize the canvas with

```
app.activeDocument.resizeCanvas(w, h, pos);

// Where 
// w is width
// h is height
// pos is position. default is AnchorPosition.MIDDLECENTER
// you probably want pos to be AnchorPosition.MIDDLELEFT
```

or just resize the whole image

```
app.activeDocument.resizeImage(960, 960, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try using

[image - image size] option instead of [image - canvas size]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to expand proportionally to your canvas then you should use the option Image > Image Size, then everything will increase proportionally to the new size, but that's not recommended if you are not using vector layers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your layers to scale up along with the canvas size change, then you should obviously use the `Image Size` option, which you seem to be aware of `Image Size` by your original post.

If you want your layers to automatically re-position themselves to account for changed canvas size... ...now that is a whole other can of worms. This would involve either A. the machine making design choices for you, or B. rules and anchors are set so the elements are responsive. As for A, that is artificial intelligence. As for B, those kinds of features you are more likely to find in a programmed document like responsive website design.

Anyway, for your purposes, it's probably best to manually re-adjust your layers after changing the canvas size. Make use of the `Align Tools`, they can help you line up layers many different ways.